# Who and where manufactured these “MIDO” bricks from the 80s?

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

I own a decent amount of these “MIDO” bricks, I thrifted them with a bunch of official Lego bricks from 1980s sets. I’ve done some research and found nothing on the brand. They are actually great quality and feel just as good as Lego. Any information will be valued, especially country of origin or manufacturer's website.

[image]

Comment: Hi Benji and welcome to Bricks.SE! You write that you'd appreciate any information, but you seem to have the brand name already - is there anything in particular you are looking for?

Comment: @zovits, yes I was wondering if there might be a website for the brand or a country of manufacture

Answer (score 7):

I was just sorting through my old brick box and found the old Mido brochure. It looks like they were produced in Israel by Isgad Ltd.[image]